# Angular Timer with RxJs : random behavior

Tags: javascript, angular, timer, rxjs, countdown

I'm working on an Angular2 project, where the user is asked to answer a list of questions within a certain amount of time for each question.

To that end, I'm using RxJs with observables and timer/countdown functions.

I have to admit I'm quite new to RxJs world, although trying to understand...

Here is a link to the project (I limited the code to the minimum) :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5-example-r3kvgy

In a few words :

1- when the page is loaded (ngAfterViewInit), the timer is created :

```
  this.timerControl$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

this.timer$ = this.timerControl$.switchMap(
  period => Observable
    .timer(0, 1000)
    .finally(() => this.loadNextQuestion())
    .map(t => period - (t + 1) / 1)
    .takeUntil(Observable.merge(Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('nextQuestionButton'), 'click'), Observable.timer(period * 1000)))
);

this.timerControl$.subscribe()
```

2- when the user clicks the button "Start test", this piece of code is executed (l1, l2 and l3 refer to level 1/2/3 questions, and the numbers represent the time for allowed for each question) :

```
this.test =  { 
  l1: [10,15,10,10,10], l2: [20,20,20], l3: [30,30] } ;
this.step = 2;
this.loadNextQuestion();
```

with :

```
 loadNextQuestion() {
    this.showQuestion = false;

if (!this.lastQuestion) { 

  if (this.question.l === 0) {//First question
    this.question.l = 1;
    this.question.l_i = 0;
  } else {

    if (this.question.l_i === (this.test['l' + this.question.l].length - 1)) { // We upgrade to superior level (1->2 or 2->3)
      this.question.l += 1;
      this.question.l_i = 0;
    } else {
      this.question.l_i += 1;

    }
  }

  //We load the right question from the test
  this.question.q = this.test['l' + this.question.l][this.question.l_i];

  // Launch timer with good delay
  this.delay = this.question.q;

  this.timerControl$.next(this.delay);

  // Is it the last question of the test?
  this.lastQuestion = (this.question.l === 3 && (this.question.l_i === (this.test['l3'].length - 1)))

  this.showQuestion = true;

} else {// Test finished
  alert("Finished")
}
```

}

3- When te user clicks "Next question", the function loadNextQuestion is fired again

**The issue** :
Everything is working well in many cases... but randomly, the next question is loaded **before** the countdown has reached 0

This could happen for the very last question, or any question during the test.

[You can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmMbQ.png)  one case where the popup window is displayed before the end of the countdown (for the last question of the test)

Not an easy bug to reproduce... you may have to try several times. If you wait a few seconds for the first questions before clicking Next, and then you click Next very quickly until the last question, then the problem may appear (the popup appears before the countdown has ended)

It would be very appreciated if you could give me some help on it !! Thanks !!